# Как реализовать список?

Tags: javascript, html

как реализовать, чтобы при загрузке сайта, список выпадал, а потом сворачивался?

```html
<div class="w-dropdown hidden_for_tablets ush_dropdown_1  source_own">
  <div class="w-dropdown-h">
    <div class="w-dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
      <a class="w-dropdown-item ms_booking" data-url="https://n16008.yclients.com/company:30089?o=&lang=" href="#"><span class="w-dropdown-item-title">ТЦ "ЗАМОК"</span></a>
      <a class="w-dropdown-item ms_booking" data-url="https://n16008.yclients.com/company:31382?o=&lang=" href="#"><span class="w-dropdown-item-title">ТЦ “ПРОМЕНАД”</span></a>
      <a class="w-dropdown-item ms_booking" data-url="https://n16008.yclients.com/company:84826?o=&lang=" href="#"><span class="w-dropdown-item-title">УЛ. РУМЯНЦЕВА 17</span></a>
      <a class="ms_booking" data-url="https://n16008.yclients.com/group:249/city:all?o=&lang=" href="#"><button class="btn-order">Записаться</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-dropdown-current">
      <a class="w-dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span class="w-dropdown-item-title">ТЦ "ЗАМОК"</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector(".w-dropdown-list").style.display = "block";
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector(".w-dropdown-list").style.display = "none";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="w-dropdown hidden_for_tablets ush_dropdown_1  source_own">
  <div class="w-dropdown-h">
    <div class="w-dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
      <a class="w-dropdown-item ms_booking" data-url="https://n16008.yclients.com/company:30089?o=&lang=" href="#"><span class="w-dropdown-item-title">ТЦ "ЗАМОК"</span></a>
      <a class="w-dropdown-item ms_booking" data-url="https://n16008.yclients.com/company:31382?o=&lang=" href="#"><span class="w-dropdown-item-title">ТЦ “ПРОМЕНАД”</span></a>
      <a class="w-dropdown-item ms_booking" data-url="https://n16008.yclients.com/company:84826?o=&lang=" href="#"><span class="w-dropdown-item-title">УЛ. РУМЯНЦЕВА 17</span></a>
      <a class="ms_booking" data-url="https://n16008.yclients.com/group:249/city:all?o=&lang=" href="#"><button class="btn-order">Записаться</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-dropdown-current">
      <a class="w-dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span class="w-dropdown-item-title">ТЦ "ЗАМОК"</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: это jquery подключать ещё нужно?

Comment: @ZoomieOS Нет, не нужно.

Comment: Не получается тогда(

Comment: @ZoomieOS Поместите скрипт ниже разметки на странице.

Comment: Всё равно не помогло

Comment: @ZoomieOS Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.

Comment: У вас работает, я без понятия почему у меня нет

Comment: @ZoomieOS Несмотря на напряжение всех моих умственных сил, пока не могу угадать, почему у Вас не работает ).

Comment: [browbar.monotone.by] вот на этом сайте

Comment: и это не получается через html код вставить